# Is it possible to use @KafkaStreamsStateStore annotation on Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams 3.0 Binder style API methods?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Is it possible to use @KafkaStreamsStateStore annotation on Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams 3.0 Binder style API methods?

It looks like if I'm placing @KafkaStreamsStateStore over my 3.0 style methods like

```
@KafkaStreamsStateStore(name="my-store", type= KafkaStreamsStateStoreProperties.StoreType.WINDOW, lengthMs=300000)
@Bean
public BiFunction<KStream<String, Long>, KStream<String, Long>, KStream<String, Long>> myStream() {
....
```

It doesn't take effect and I get the following exception during application startup:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'streamsBuilderFactoryManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore my-store is not added yet.
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore my-store is not added yet.
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.java:83)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore my-store is not added yet.
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:280)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.java:74)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore my-store is not added yet.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.connectProcessorAndStateStore(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:662)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.connectProcessorAndStateStores(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:601)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.graph.StatefulProcessorNode.writeToTopology(StatefulProcessorNode.java:92)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.InternalStreamsBuilder.buildAndOptimizeTopology(InternalStreamsBuilder.java:304)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder.build(StreamsBuilder.java:562)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:262)
    ... 50 more
```

Here's how I'm calling my processor, attaching it to the store within the `myStream()` method:

```
...
.transformValues(() -> new MyTransformer<>(), "my-store")
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use @KafkaStreamsStateStore annotation to define a Store with 3.0 RELEASE. According to the docs (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_state_store)  you should either use materializedAs property

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-1.consumer.materializedAs: my-store
```

or define a StoreBuilder bean:

```
    @Bean
    public StoreBuilder myStore() {
        return Stores.windowStoreBuilder(
            Stores.inMemoryWindowStore("mystore", duration,windowSize, false),
            ...);
    }
```